# jQuery DOM manipulation of table lost after submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Based on a TextBox "autocomplete" functionality the user can select amongst a list of results, the user would then select one of theese results and add it to a "basket", the user performs multiple rapid searches and adds or removes items from this basket.

At the moment i've used a table as the "Basket". once the user is satisfied with the basket, the user submits the basket to the server and the server loops trough the basket and updates the database.

I'm trying to manipulate a table with jQuery, the problem is that once the postback happens, the DOM manipulations are removed.

The table looks like the following.

```
 <asp:Table ID="Basket"
 runat="server"
 EnableViewState="False">
     <asp:TableHeaderRow TableSection="TableHeader">
         <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
         <asp:TableHeaderCell>Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
         <asp:TableHeaderCell>Quantity</asp:TableHeaderCell>
     </asp:TableHeaderRow> </asp:Table>
```

with jQuery i can modify the table, add rows, delete them and all is fine and dandy. I then have a submit button

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" />`

in the Click event of the button i loop through the rows of my table

```
foreach (TableRow row in this.Basket.Rows)
{
            if (row.TableSection != TableRowSection.TableBody) { continue; }
}
```

This is where the problem is, the Table is reset to the initial state only containing 1 row. Considering i've disabled the ViewState, I would think the control would mimic what is posted back. But clearly something makes it reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about this all wrong, Javascript is front end and without you telling the server that rows have been added, it will never know and thus it only adds one row as you tell it to do.

You will need to save the values somehow

Comment: the intention is to create a "basket" only on that page, and perform a batch submit, once submitted the id of the item and the quantity is stored server side, this would be to prevent constant chatter, and make the userinterface more desktop like

Comment: Yep. I second that. JS is a client side technology, you need to implement the communication between the JS client-side code and your server-side code. If you don't submit the update to the server-side in some way, how is it to know? HTTP is a disconnected protocol.

Comment: you COULD do it this way, and it is by far not the only way to do this but:

I would add the values to a hidden field (in JSON) and parse it server side.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi the point of the submit  button would be to traverse the data from the form post that just got posted, i'm aware I could make a hidden field and condense what I write in the table into a string, and then parse that string, but it feels silly when the table is in the form that is part of the post request :)

Comment: @thmsn
You are thinking about as a stateful environment when in fact it is stateless, AFAIK ASP:table does not remember your changes to the table because they are not submitted to the server

Comment: @Kenned what would you do then, I have a textbox, where I perform searches, this gives a list of results, I can select one of theese results and add them to the "basket", the point of this is that you perform lots of searches rapidly and add them to a basket, and then submit the basket.

Comment: @thmsn - I was thinking more along the lines of an ajax update, since you are already useing jQuery, which makes this very easy. Using hidden fields would be silly at this day and age. Consider that a server-side table is translated to html table tags, but I don't think the reverese happens automaticlly.

Comment: The point of the table is mainly showing the user what they have added so far, I would just expect asp.net to recreate the table considering its in the form tag.

Comment: this is my first jQuery project as of such, in my earlier prototypes of this project i've used updatepanels and partial postbacks having the table modified server side, but it appeared to be rather slow.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi - could you elaborate on what a jquery ajax update would accomplish compared to normal updatepanel behaviour?

Comment: @thmsn - I have not used updatepanels before, so I can't compare the two for you. I use $.ajax ALOT. It is light weight and very flexible. It allows you to handle all the different readystates, if you have a use for that. It's biggest plus is that it does alot of the data manipulation / type conversion of the request and response data for you.

Comment: Well, maybe a hidden field is silly, but it is indeed a very quick implementation. in my mvc projects i usually call my controller async  with arguments, but I asume you are using webforms. so you could use $.ajax() to call the page with the results when adding them